# Error en LoginTest Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel-6, tdd, dusk

Favor su ayuda con este error.
Estoy utilizando laravel Dusk, para testear el login. Me esta dando este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguí la documentación donde sale este mismo ejemplo. cree la base independiente para los tests, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar. Es como si no lograse crear el usuario, siendo que coloqué que se ejecuten las migraciones.

Esta es mi clase LoginTest

```
namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @test
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function registered_users_can_login()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email' => 'fmorales@demo.com'
        ]);
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', 'fmorales@demo.com')
                    ->type('password', 'password')
                    ->press('#login-btn')
                    //->assertPathIs('/')
                    ->assertAuthenticated()
            ;
        });
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.
Gracias de antemano.

(En los screenshots de error, me muestra una imagen en blanco con dos corchetes [], imagino que tiene que ver con el mensaje de array is not empty.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente el test estaba bien, pero lo estaba ejecutando desde el ide y no desde la terminal.

Al correr desde la terminal con:

```
php artisan dusk --filter="registered_users_can_login"
```

, este pasa sin problemas.

Bueno, esto fue por mi poca experiencia  trabajando con test.